# Jasmine unit test case for dynamic character count

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

Can anyone give me example of writing test case for checking if the 
     function within the keyup event is called in jquery and jasmine.
     I am fairly new to jquery and jasmine so sorry for the errors.
     This program displays the remaining character count as the user enters the characters in the input field.and I'm stuck with test cases
     I tried as follows

`fixture.html`: This is the fixture

```
 <input id="text" name="text" size="100" maxlength="65"></input>
 <span id="count"></span>
```

`script.js`: This is the script file with code to calculate remaining 
    characters

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var txt = $('#text');
    var remainingChar = $('#count');
    var maxLengthBox = txt.attr('maxLength');
    remainingChar.html(maxLengthBox);

    txt.keyup(function () {
        updateChars(remainingChar, maxLengthBox, txt)
    });
});

function updateChars(remainingChar, maxLengthBox, txt) {
    var remChar = maxLengthBox - $(txt).val().length;
    if (remChar < 0) {
        remChar = 0;
    }
    remainingChar.html(remChar);
    return remChar;
}
```

This is one of the test cases please help me here because it's not calling the function after triggering the keyup how do I test it
1. if the function `updateChars(remainingChar,maxLengthBox,txt)` is            getting called and executed
2. how to check the correct `remainingChar` count is returned

TestCase starts here:
The code is working fine but I need help in writing test case for            "checking if correct character count is displayed " as on triggering `keyup` function the inner `updateChars` function is not called for me in the test case

```
beforeEach(function () {
    loadFixtures('Fixture.html');
    txt = $('#text');
    remainingChar = $('#count');
    maxLengthBox = txt.attr('maxLength');
    remainingChar.html(maxLengthBox);
});

it("checking remaining characters", function () { 
    txt.val('hello');   //entering hello into that text field

    //triggering keyup and expecting this to call the updateChars function
    txt.trigger('keyup');  

    expect(updateChars).toHaveBeenCalled():
});
```

Comment: updated your question but there is an extra parenthesis `}` in your first code. Are you missing something there?

Comment: i am not it was just a typing error .... thank you for updating the question :) ...i gave it a shot to check it.I am using fixtures for the file from fixtures i am defining the variables in the jquery for ex -> var a1= ('#title'); .Taking the title id from the fixture input text field and declaring it in the jquery structure .

Comment: Where is `functionwithinkeyup` defined?

Comment: I have updated the code :) .I didnt as i was still working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm assuming you are running your test directly in the browser, right? And by your code, I'm assuming that `updateChars` function is global so it is attached to `window`.

Saying that, what you need is a `spy`, in `jasmine` we use the function `spyOn`, here is an example:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    //here we setup the "spy"
    spyOn(window, 'updateChars');
});

it("checking remaining characters", function() { 
    txt.val('hello');
    txt.trigger('keyup');

    expect(updateChars).toHaveBeenCalled():
});
```

This is just an illustrative example that you need to adjust to your needs.

**Some notes**
I see in your code this line `loadFixtures('Fixture.html');`, I don't know what it actually does, but if it is an async call, then you will need to use the `done` callback in the `beforeEach`.

Another illustrative example with an asynchronous call:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    //here we setup the "spy"
    spyOn(window, 'updateChars');

    //supose this is a promise and we can call .then
    loadFixtures('Fixture.html')
    .then(function(){
        txt = $('#text');
        remainingChar = $('#count');
        maxLengthBox = txt.attr('maxLength');
        remainingChar.html(maxLengthBox);

        done(); //finally
    }); 

});

it("checking remaining characters", function(done) { 
    txt.val('hello');
    txt.trigger('keyup');

    expect(updateChars).toHaveBeenCalled():

    done();
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the response it was very helpful :)

Comment: @SamanthaB I'm glad I could help, don't forget to vote and/or accept the answer if it was helpful :-)