# Timeout Async callback in karma jasmine firefox runner

Tags: angular, unit-testing, firefox, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm having some random timeouts while running Jasmine unit tests with `angular` framework using `karma-firefox-launcher`.
It happens in random angular components tests. Do you have any idea on how to troubleshoot the problem?

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL. in spec/main.js (line 151483)
attempt/timeoutId<@node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4470:23 [<root>]
```

I'm using `jasmine` packages:

```
"@angular/core": "2.4.10",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
"@types/jasmine-jquery": "^1.5.32",
"jasmine": "^2.99.0",
"jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-jasmine-jquery": "^0.1.1"
```

Comment: A test methode seems to be faulty, Caused by async service requests mostly

Comment: Really hard to help without an example of your test

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466803/jasmine-unit-test-case-for-dynamic-character-count/47481839#47481839) is an example of an `async` test. Also, you can [read the docs about async](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async)